# Разбить строку explode php

Tags: php

Есть строка

```
$a = "Зал,panoram.swf;Спальня,panoram.swf";
```

Нужно разбить эту строку таким образом чтобы потом можно было сделать вывод циклом.

```
foreach($a as $key => $val) {
             echo "<a href='&panoram=panoram.swf'>Зал</a>";
        }
Проблема в том что я не могу только Зал и panoram.swf как две переменные типа $a и $b что потом подставить в код.
```

Comment: Ну, вы ж сами написали решение в своём ответе: [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). Или вы хотите, чтобы за вас разжевали и проглотили?

Comment: Нет проблема не в этом я пишу explode он мне выдает все значения что прилетели с базы, а мне нужно их разбить на две переменные, циклом.
echo "<a href='&panoram=panoram.swf'>Зал</a>"; - Чтобы два раза такое выходило, а значения подставлялись

Comment: @musing, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 2):

```
list($a,$b) = explode($delimiter,$string); //две переменные - первые два значения.
$arr = explode($delimiter,$string); //массив
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте два раза explode.

```
$line = "Зал,panoram.swf;Спальня,panoram.swf";
$ar1 = explode(";",$line);
foreach($ar1 as $key => $val){
    $ar2[$key] = explode(",",$val);
    echo "<a href="&panoram='.$ar2[$key]['1'].'">'.$ar2[$key]['0'].'</a>";
}
```